# How to share folders into two Ubuntu distributions in a dual-boot?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm interested in installing Ubuntu Studio 16.04 aside Ubuntu.

How can I share files between the two OS? I want to share the user files for both OS or, if there are not too many difficulties, share the `home` folder. I do not know how to do any of these procedures.

I'll appreciate if someone explain this to me. My apologies if the question seems duplicate, but I only find how to share files between Ubuntu and Windows, and I don't know how to answer my question from that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a (or use an existing) shared partition that both distros can mount.

Check with `fdisk` or `gparted` if `/home` is already a partition by itself, if that's the case you could mount the other OS' partition from `/etc/fstab`

Ideally, if you have the same `UID` (user ID) and `GID` (group ID) you will be able to maintain file ownership between OS'es.

If you need to create a new partition you may need to resize one or more existing partitions to create space for the new partition. `Gparted` is able to do this.

Comment: Ok. I'm not an expert on this. If I put `fdisk -l` in the terminal, this show `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied`.

Then I open Disks and I see **Filesystem. Partition 1. 537 MB FAT**

**Filesystem. Partition 2. 495 GB Ext4**

**Swap. Partition 3. 4.2 GB SWAP**

**Free Space 1.1 MB**

So I think that the `home` is not a partition itself. Am I wrong? How I can use `Gparted` to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: fdisk will need to be run as root. Apart from that, I don't see how you can dual-boot off one disk with only one Ext4 (root filesystem) partition. Or do you have multiple disks? In any case, starting up gparted (as root) will allow you to resize a (non-live) partition. What does cat /proc/partitions say? Are there multiple disks there?

Comment: No. In this moment I only have Ubuntu 16.04 installed. I'm interested in do a Dual-boot with Ubuntu Studio but when I put the bootable usb (with Ubuntu Studio) I feel lost, because they offers me the option of manage the partitions but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Ah, I understand now. What you do is boot off the USB version and start gparted there (enter root password when prompted). In the top Gparted menu bar go Gparted - Devices - and select your other OS disk (probably the HDD or SSD). From the list of partitions, resize the main ext4 partition so that there's enough for you to hold your shared data (e.g. 1GB). Then create a new partition in the free space (ext4), click apply and let gparted do its thing. Now you have a space that you can mount from both machines. It still needs some work to further set up, but see how you go.